# is Valgrind errors normal in Python

Tags: python, valgrind

I am facing the problem python along with valgrind. I was getting default valgrind warnings messages. I have created the sample.py. sample.py file does not have any code. I created empty py file to confirm that my code does not have any memory leaks.

Following is the valgrind command that I am using in command line:

```
**valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --gen-suppressions=all --log-file=msm_suppress.log -v /home/arunspra/py_src/Python-2.7.5/python sample.py**
```

I was getting plenty of valgrind warnings.

I surfed in the google and I got to know that i need to configure python by disabling pymalloc. As said by technical peoples, If pymalloc was disabled, we would not got any memory related errors. But i was getting the memory related error. Following is my command that i used to disable pymalloc:

```
**./configure --without-pymalloc --with-pydebug
make**
```

Then I ran above said valgrind command. I was getting 1299 valgrind warnings. If i enable pymalloc, I was getting only 108 valgrind warnings.

Following is my software versions:

```
**Cent os: 7.3
Python: 2.7.5
Valgrind: 3.12.0**
```

PS: If i configure and build python, i was getting an Import Error: No module named netifaces. I am using netifaces in my project. If i use system inbuilt python, i am not getting netifaces import error.

Can anyone please advice me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valgrind suppressions file to sanely use valgrind with Python.  Here's the official one, which works for me: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/valgrind-python.supp

Comment: Probably add them to your suppressions file.